# Android Layout problemAt the certain part of screen, i sometimes need to display a button and sometimes a TextView

Tags: android, button, layout, textview, screen

At the certain part of screen, i sometimes need to display a button and sometimes a TextView. When the Button is visible, TextView is invisible and vice-versa.(at the same place). How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple to achieve. In your layout have both button and textview in the same place. make one of them visibile and hide other one using **android:visibility="visible"/android:visibility="gone"**

form code you can hide and show accordingly them accordingly by using

```
View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) 
View.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />

<Button  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response." In your layout have both button and textview in the same place" .How can i do this ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to add some code for you